# How to Populate Computed Field with node tags/terms

Tags: drupal-6, tags, cck, taxonomy

I'm trying to fill a computed field with the terms/tags associated with the node, along with the body. Getting the body in is fine using "$node->body" but I'm not sure how to bring in the tags?

The VID for the vocab i want is "4" - so I want all VID 4 terms that the article has been tagged with to display in this field, along with the body.

I'm doing this for custom search purposes, where one can search both tags AND body text at the same time, but I'm sure the code will come in handy for future projects also.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Here's the complete code I've entered into the "computed code" box for my computed field:

```
// Specify the vocabulary you want to pull tags from for the node
$vid = 4;

// String together the term array with a pipe between each term
$terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vid);
if ($terms) {foreach ($terms as $term) {$node_terms .= ' | ' . $term->name;}}

// Merge terms and body into field value
$node_field[0]['value'] = $node_terms ." <br><br>". $node->body;
```

Hope that can help anyone with similar issues in the future :)